# EsLint Expected an Identifier and instead saw 'let'

Tags: javascript, eslint

this is one of my first times coding with Javascript so I figured I would come here for help since I can't find info anywhere else.

Basically, I am getting the error message above and my code looks like this

```
let interfaceItems = [
{
    text: '7',
    value: 7,
},
{
    text: '8',
    value: 8,
```

(etc)

This is at the very beginning of my .js document. Why is it saying this? How would I go about fixing it in future?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you test your code with a linter make sure you are using the correct settings for the code you are testing. For instance you are using `let`, that keyword wasn't introduced until ECMAScript 2015 (es6). So you would have to make sure your linter was setup to test against that version and not ES5 which is probably what it was defaulting to use.

In the case of ESLint you can change the `parserOptions.ecmaVersion` property in the `.eslintrc.json` file like so:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    }
}
```

[Refer to the configuration help page for other configuration options](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)